# Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation vs Riccati equation

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

Most of the literature on Reinforcement Learning discuss Hamilton Jacobi Bellman equations for optimality. In dynamics however Ricatti equations are used. I am curious if there are any parallels between the two equations for optimality? How do one differ from the other?

Comment: Hi: ricatti results from kalman filter theory. hjb results from optimal control theory. not sure of the relation but, if there is one, it's not obvious. I would google for them together and see if anything pops up.

Comment: @markleeds What I read is ricatti also results from optimal control. This is why I was trying to find a link between the two. Will keep looking, thanks.

Comment: that's news to me but it definitely then indicates a serious connection. there should be a ton of material out there for sure. I'm sorry that I can't be of more help.

Comment: Hi: I don't have time to read it but his talks about solving a differential riccati and then using that to solve hjb. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-323-principles-of-optimal-control-spring-2008/lecture-notes/lec4.pdf

Comment: @markleeds thanks a lot. I will give it a read.